# Develop a modular application, load modules automatically

Tags: android

I need help! :-)

I have an application and want to make it modular, but the modules will be loaded automatically. Let me explain:

Consider an application "B" (as a conventional project of android). When I access the application "A" will appear a button: Load application "A", but "A" search and found "B" are installed on system automatically.

I would like application "A" detects automatically (according to some rules) that "B" is a module of the application "A".

Thanks for all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

idea 1 :
you can list the installed applications using the getInstalledPackages function of the packagemanager

idea 2:
make a module register service which can then be queried

idea 3: create a file on the sdcard which lists the installed apps

Then you can use intents to start the apps

Comment: Nice! I like this! I will test this solution!

Comment: but how register activity of other application on AndroidManifest in execution time?

Comment: Im not 100% sure but i think you dont have to if you use it like this :  Intent i = new Intent(); 
     i.setClassName("yourdoman.yourpackage", "yourdomain.yourpackage.yourclass");

Comment: or something like this  ntent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
    intent.setComponent(ComponentName.unflattenFromString("com.google.android.maps.mytracks/com.google.android.apps.mytracks.MyTracks"));
    intent.addCategory("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER");
    startActivity(intent);

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need to use fully qualified application names to query whether or not an application is installed.

Then you'll have to use intent filters on the application B so that it's only launchable from application A.

Hope this helps.

Comment: think: we have 2 applications A and B. A loads B (not register on manifest file)... because the ideia is do N applications loaded by A.

Comment: Yes... you need to create an intent filter that only allows those applications to be started by the program you want.

Comment: Great! :D  Make sure you upvote/mark as correct answers that solve your problem!